# Method not found. error when using Google my business API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-my-business-api

I am getting 404 from accouts list function by using google api client.

I have already access token by using OAuth2.0.
In addition to this, I already enable the Google My Business API via https://console.developers.google.com for OAuth 2.0.

■Here is environemnt

> PHP 7.2.3
>
> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
>
> google/apiclient ^2.5

The function I want to execute is as following.
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/list

I install google client libray by using composer from following link.
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Since google my business library is seprated, I use this program.
https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples

The steps to produce 404 is...

```php
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("post_dev");       // app name
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAccessToken($credential);
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage");                                                                                        
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage");
    $gmbService = new \Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);
    $results = $gmbService->accounts->listAccounts();
```

The variable $credential has following values.

```
client_id
client_secret
access_token
expires_in
refresh_token
```

After executing program, I am getting 404 erros like follwoing.

```
Google_Service_Exception[
  404
]: {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Method not found.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Method not found.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ],
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you are trying to interact with the Google My Business API using a non-whitelisted project.

I faced the same issue. In my case, I submitted my project for whitelisting to unlock Google My Business API library.

Then, a couple weeks after that I created a new project under the same Google Cloud Platform account, just to set a more appropriate name. HERE was the root of the issue!

Even if you see the GMB library enabled at the account level, it works only at the PROJECT level. That's why you are getting 404 errors.

So, I switched everything to my original project (Consent screen settings, Oauth clients, etc)... The same on my localhost application, developed with Laravel Lumen 7.

After these couple changes, everything worked fine!

**NOTE:** Google allows you to whitelist 1 project per account ONLY! If your project/application were approved by Google, USE IT! Instead creating new ones.

Comment: You're welcome, hope you fix it. If you don't, let me know @LeoS

Comment: having the same problem on a newer API @arau.  Guys I'm speaking to at the goog will get back to me I'm guessing, but in the meantime, is there a place to go to "whitelist my project" for the API?  I could have sworn I saw it in my console somewhere but don't see it now.  My API list does show that I've been given access to the private API at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with your access token. It cant find the method you are using. Google_Service_MyBusiness  is not part of the Google api php client library.

The my Business API is unlike the other apis, it is not listed in the API directory available through the Discovery API and it requires a developer key and project acceptance into My Business.   There for it cant be generated when the library generation script runs.

Im going though some channels to get that documentation page updated.

### note from team  Nov 1, 2018

There is a [tool](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/pull/145) on the way that will help developers maintain their own version of such service classes. When it is ready and you have a project with My Business enabled you should be able to run:

```
export API_KEY=yourkey
bin/generate 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4&key=$API_KEY' generated-output
```

and then you can move the contents of generated-output/mybusiness-v4 anywhere you want in your include path.
That discovery URL has been known to change as new versions come out so keep and eye on https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/

Im waiting to hear the status of this.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for that! I really appreciate it. When it is updated, please share the link to it :)

Comment: Check my update there may be a tool you can use to generate it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Just wondering where "bin/generate" comes from? Do I just export like this? "export API_KEY=yourkey bin/generate 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4&key=$API_KEY' generated-output"

Comment: Probably something related to the tool that was created https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/pull/145  but theres a comment from Jan 31, 2019 that says its not working.

Comment: Okay, I will look into it.

Comment: wget https://github.com/mattwhisenhunt/google-api-php-client-services/archive/generator_clean.zip

Comment: php bin/generate 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4&key=$API_KEY' generated-output

Comment: Also, the URL provided by them dose not exist. I got this......{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Method not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}

Comment: When google granted your application for access to Google my bussness API did it come with any contact info. I would try to contact them directly.  This is a very exclusive API so i would assume it came with some kind of support form their end

Comment: Thanks for your sugguestion. I just send a message to support team.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217590/discussion-between-leo-s-and-daimto).

Comment: I'm facing EXACTLY the same problem. Same setup, Google API client library + MyBusiness sample PHP code (This one: https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples).

Everything, wrapped up in Laravel Lumen 7.

Result: { "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Method not found.", "errors": [ { "message": "Method not found.", "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound" } ], "status": "NOT_FOUND" } }

Any suggestion?!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I could not call the API is "my company already has a whitelisted project to access the Google My Business API. At this time, they are only whitelisting one project per business.". Therefore, I could not call API.

Answer (score 0):

So far I'm able to use the PHP Library here - https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples/previousVersions

But the answer above was a huge help - I had EXACTLY the same issue, had "tidied up" my projects - after being granted access to the Google My Business API and seeing it available for my other projects I assumed incorrectly that my other projects would be able to use it - wrong! Very glad I found the answer here.  Luckily I was able to restore the project I'd deleted, and using that one it worked straight away.